# Delphi service won't start

Tags: delphi, service, startup

I have a problem with a service I coded in Delphi. It's not starting and I can't seem to find the problem with it. It was working well 2 weeks ago, and without any change to the service, it suddenly stopped working.
The service is in charge of updating a huge system, but it's independent of if. My service gets the URL of a hotfix, downloads it and executes it. Nothing more, nothing less.
The system it is supposed to update has some other services and stuff running in the background, so it has a little tool to restart all the background stuff all at once (including my service). At my office, we have like 70 or so computers running everyday the hole system with my service included and it was working fine. We have almost all versions of windows (XP, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2003, and even Windows 10). One day suddenly, it stopped restarting with this little tool I told you about. The first thing that came into my mind was to try to start it manually, but haven't had any luck either.
My biggest problem, is that I have no clue of what can be happening. The only place where I can see some kind of log is in the windows event manager, and it's not helpful at all. The error says:

`The XXX service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.`

I've searched the web and couldn't find anything useful. All the pages related to this error says that this error has something to do with the windows services time out, or that it has something to do with NetFramework 1.1 and windows 2003 server. It's neither the case, we have instaled NetFramework 4 with the last update in some of the computers where it's crashing and as I told you, it's crashing in may different versions of windows. About the timeout, the error is shown right after I hit start in the service manager, it won't wait the 30 seconds timeout.

I have a log machine in the service but it's of no use, the error is happening somewhere before the "ServiceStart" method. I have this code:

```
procedure TMyService.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
    try
    LogFile.Write('TTMyService.ServiceStart'); //This is my logging machine
    Started := True;
    InitializeService; //Sets some variables
    InitializeTimer; //Start a timer where all the magic happens
  except
     on e:Exception Do
      LogFile.Write('TTMyService.ServiceStart - ' + e.Message);
   end;
end;
```

This is not logging anything, not even "TMyService.ServiceStart". One idea I had but it's not working either, is to replace the TApplication VCL class. I copied all the content of the "Vcl.SvcMgr" file to a new one, modifying it like this (I only added the LogFile.Write Stuff):

```
procedure TServiceApplication.Run;
var
  ServiceStartTable: TServiceTableEntryArray;
  ServiceCount, i, J: Integer;
  StartThread: TServiceStartThread;
begin
{$IF NOT DEFINED(CLR)}
  AddExitProc(DoneServiceApplication);
{$ENDIF}
  if FindSwitch('INSTALL') then
    RegisterServices(True, FindSwitch('SILENT'))
  else if FindSwitch('UNINSTALL') then
    RegisterServices(False, FindSwitch('SILENT'))
  else
  begin
    Vcl.Forms.Application.OnException := OnExceptionHandler;
    ServiceCount := 0;
    for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
      if Components[i] is TService then Inc(ServiceCount);
    SetLength(ServiceStartTable, ServiceCount + 1);
{$IF NOT DEFINED(CLR)}
    FillChar(ServiceStartTable[0], SizeOf(TServiceTableEntry) * (ServiceCount + 1), 0);
{$ENDIF}
    J := 0;
    for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
      if Components[i] is TService then
      begin
{$IF DEFINED(CLR)}
        ServiceStartTable[J].lpServiceName := Components[i].Name;
        ServiceStartTable[J].lpServiceProc := ServiceMainDelegate;
{$ELSE}
        ServiceStartTable[J].lpServiceName := PChar(Components[i].Name);
        ServiceStartTable[J].lpServiceProc := @ServiceMain;
{$ENDIF}
        Inc(J);
      end;
    StartThread := TServiceStartThread.Create(ServiceStartTable);
    try
      while not Vcl.Forms.Application.Terminated do
      try
        Vcl.Forms.Application.HandleMessage;
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          LogFile.Write('TServiceApplication.Run - ' + e.Message);
          DoHandleException(E);
        end;
      end;
      Vcl.Forms.Application.Terminate;
{$IF DEFINED(CLR)}
      DoneServiceApplication;
{$ENDIF}
      if StartThread.ReturnValue <> 0 then
      begin
        LogFile.Write('TServiceApplication.Run - ' + SysErrorMessage(StartThread.ReturnValue));
        FEventLogger.LogMessage(SysErrorMessage(StartThread.ReturnValue));
      end;
    finally
      StartThread.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

`Sorry, I don't know how to mark my changes in bold or in red to make it easier for you to see them`

This is working, now I can get some "useful" log, but it's not helping either. I get:

`TServiceApplication.Run - The parameter is incorrect`

And the service won't anymore in my machine (where it was still working). So far, I know for sure of 15 machines where it's not working, and I have no access to try in the other 65. Somehow, in my machine, where I'm developing the service, it's still working if I comment the "Tapplication" changes.

Another problem I have, is that I can't do as many tests as I would like in the machines where it's breaking, because they are being used by other people and every test I ask them to do, stop the from working...

Before I forget, don't know if it's relevant, but to get the URL of the hotfix, the service connects (in my machine), to a local web service hosted on IIS.

Any Ideas?
Is this clear enough? Any doubt you have, please ask them! :D I'm really lost, and this have high priority :'(

Thanks in advance!
Nicolás López

**New data 1:**

In a New test, Reinstalling the service in one of the machines, seams to fix the problem. But Without knowing the cause of the problem, that's useless.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. tried the below answers but no luck. Can you please tell me how I can make it functional?

Answer (score 1):

Your log message `TServiceApplication.Run - The parameter is incorrect` means that `StartThread.ReturnValue` is 87 (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`). The only way that can happen is if `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` failed when called by `TServiceStartThread.Execute()`.  `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` takes only 1 parameter - the `ServiceStartTable` array that `TServiceApplication.Run()` sets up. That array contains service names and `Main()` callbacks for receiving SCM messages.  So something is wrong with that array and you need to find out what it is. It is probably not being populated correctly, or is being corrupted before `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` is called.

To diagnose your problem, you will have to use the IDE debugger to step through the `TService` startup code.  That means using the debugger's **Attach to Process** feature, as the IDE cannot auto-start a service for debugging. You have to issue a start to the SCM first, and then attach the debugger to the resulting process (click on the "Show system processes" checkbox in the attach dialog).  That also means tweaking your project code to make the startup delay until the debugger is attached.  I usually handle that in the `OnStart` event, by calling `IsDebuggerPresent()` in a loop, but since your `OnStart` is not triggering, you will have to do the delay earlier in the startup logic, such as in the main DPR before `TApplication` starts initializing the `TService` object.

There is simply not enough information in this discussion so far for anyone here to diagnose the problem for you.

Comment: Remy, Thanks for you answer but I don't think that's the problem of my service. The only way I get this error, is after I modified it to use my own version of `Vcl.SvcMgr`, otherwise, it will work fine in my machine. I've commented it because I thought it might be useful for someone to know it. I think the real problem of the service is somewhere else. Probably, the problem with the array, is that some unit is using the original `Vcl.SvcMgr`. I know my attempt to fix it modifying it it's not the healthiest but i had to try it anyway ;) I'm kinda lost here...

Comment: Let's work backwards. The only way that `OnStart` would not be triggered (assuming it is assigned) is if either the service's `TServiceThread` object is not created at all, or gets terminated before its `Execute()` method is called (`TThread` checks its `Terminated` property before calling `Execute()`). `TServiceThread` is not created if `TService.Main()` is not called, or if `RegisterServiceCtrlHandler()` fails when called by `TService.Main()`...

Comment: ... `Main()` is not called if `TServiceApplication.DispatchServiceMain()` is not called at all, or does not find the `TService` object whose `Name` matches the name passed as a parameter to `Main()`. `DispatchServiceMain()` is not called if `ServiceMain()` is not called. And `ServiceMain()` is not called if `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` fails.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problem:

- > The XXX service failed to start due to the following error: 
  >   The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
- the `TService.OnStart` or `TService.OnExecute` events where never fired.
- the services's path to executables (services.msc -> right click on the service -> properties) was set like this: 
  `C:\test\TrucServer.exe /startedbyscm:A357F915-40E33CD5-trucServer`

=> The solution was to reinstall the service (uninstall `sc.exe delete "Truc Server"`, then install `C:\test\TrucServer.exe -install`). The services's path to executables is now set like this: `C:\test\TrucServer.exe` and the service starts normally.

I did not try to insert logs in TServiceApplication class, but your error message: `TServiceApplication.Run - The parameter is incorrect` seems to confirm my solution could correspond to your problem as in my case the `/startedbyscm:A357F915-40E33CD5-trucServer` parameter seems to be the culprit.

I did not try too to track the error message in Vcl.SvcMgr.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I've fixed this a long time ago. If I'm recall correctly, it was a problem with a component having a wrong parameter seting on design. My service connects to a server to do it's stuff. I think it was the URL or the port or something like that was wrong, As it was Fixed in a component at design, the service won't even start.
Is there a way to close this question?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was `TServiceDesc.displayName`. I tried to `/install` and `/uninstall` and on uninstall the name could not be found. Because it could not be found on `/uninstall`, the server manager could not find it that it has started either. So the status in the "Services" was always "Starting". Why some names are OK and others not I cant tell. There was nothing special about it.

```
DisplayName := "Name DB Service";
```

It did not work. So I made the `exe` and `displayName` exactly the same. Not sure how this happens, but the reason for the error is the name of the form of the service, the name of the executable and the DisplayName. All this three together somehow get mixed up.